# Trying to find find minimum value of numbers entered in Java

Tags: java

So this program is supposed to be able to read in any amount of numbers and come out with the mean, total, and min/max. Numbers are entered and the loop stops once 0 is entered(0 does not count towards min/total etc) I am stuck on the min value. I know it's not supposed to be hard coded to 0 but how else would I set it to take the lowest value within the loop?

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double sum = 0, maxVal = 0,minVal = 0, average = 0, number;
    int count = 0;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while((number = input.nextDouble()) != 0)
    {
        sum += number;
        count++;
        if(number < minVal)
        {
            minVal = number;
        }
        if(number > maxVal)
        {
            maxVal = number;
        }
    }
    average = sum / count;
    System.out.println("Total Count: " + count);
    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
    System.out.println("Mean: " + average);
    System.out.println("Max Value: " + maxVal);
    System.out.println("Min Value: " + minVal);
}
```

}

Comment: If `minValue` starts at 0, then you need something < 0 to trigger the update.

Comment: Start `minVal` at something like `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize `min` and `max` to zero and then compare with user input, unless a value is positive you won't set `max` (or negative to set `min`). Change the initial values like

```
double sum = 0, maxVal = Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY,
        minVal = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY, average = 0, number;
```

instead of setting both to `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize both `minVal` and `maxVal` with the first entered number and only then start the loop.

```
double sum = 0, maxVal, minVal, average = 0, number;
int count = 0;
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

maxVal = minVal = number = input.nextDouble();
while(number != 0) {
    ...
    number = input.nextDouble())
}
```

It's a "classic" textbook solution.